# Create a Function that displays N or P depending on integer entered

Tags: c, arguments

Yo! so I'm starting to learn how to code on my own and for this exercise I have to create a function that displays ’N’ or ’P’ depending on the integer’s sign entered as a parameter. If n is negative, display ’N’. If n is positive or null, display ’P’. I've managed to do that and come up with a main that works. ALLOWED FUNCTION IS WRITE (no atoi etc)

```
void    ft_is_negative(int n)
{
    if (n >= 0)
    {
        write(1, "P", 1);
    }
    else
    {
        write(1, "N", 1);
    }
}

   int  main()
{
    int i;

    i = 200;
    ft_is_negative(i);
}
```

**However** I've been trying to get used to using arguments in my main but I've been struggling to get a working main when I use them. Here, with this one I simply get the carriage ("\n"), and I just can't figure out why (it's probably obvious but I can't see it). Thanks for the help in advance, if you don't directly want to give me the answer that's fine just point me in the right direction please.

```
void    ft_is_negative(int n)
{
    if (n >= 0)
    {
        write(1, "P", 1);
    }
    else
    {
        write(1, "N", 1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        while (argv[1])
        {
            ft_is_negative(*argv[1]);
        }
    }
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (argc != 2)` Check this condition. Try giving 2 arguments (lile `./a.out hoge fuga`) and you will get an inifinite `P`s or `N`s.

Comment: You probably want to do your action if `argc==2` (so argv[1] will be available) not if `argc!=2` (argv[1] might not be available). I don't understand the intention of your while loop. But I assume you are expecting input like `./program -123` so you probably want to pass something like `atoi(argv[1])` (the integer -123) instead of `*argv[1]` which will be the value of the first character entered (the value 45 for a dash character).

Comment: Is using standard library functions (like `atoi()`) allowed?

Comment: @MikeCAT no using standard library functions isn't allowed (pretty sure I'll have to code an atoi myself down the line)

Comment: @MikeCAT you're right I do end up with an infinite loop when I set (argc == 2) so I'm probably doing something wrong

Comment: @EdmCoff I put the while loop there because when I didn't use argv it wouldn't compile so that while loop was just a way to bypass that (there is probably a better way to go about it). Unfortunately I can't use atoi

Comment: I assume that means sscanf etc. are out too. In that case, I would write your version of atoi and pass argv[1] to it. Then pass the result of your atoi to ft_is_negative.

Comment: You can get rid of the `while` loop. You are already using `argv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `if (argc != 2)` is wrong. If you want to check if exactly 1 argument is given, it should be `if (argc == 2)`.
- `while (argv[1])` is wrong. It may be an infinite loop because `argv[1]` is not updated in the loop.

To check if the passed value is negative, you should check:

- If the first character is `-`
- There are character other than `0` after that
- There are no invalid characters

It can be done like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        char* p = argv[1];
        int is_minus = 0, contain_nonzero = 0, contain_invalid = 0, contain_valid = 0;
        if (*p == '-')
        {
            is_minus = 1;
            p++;
        }
        else if (*p == '+')
        {
            p++;
        }
        for (; *p != '\0'; p++)
        {
            if ('0' <= *p && *p <= '9')
            {
                contain_valid = 1;
                if (*p != '0') contain_nonzero = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                contain_invalid = 1;
            }
        }
        if (contain_invalid || !contain_valid)
        {
            /* contain invalid character or no character (except for sign) */
            write(1, "invalid", 7);
        }
        else if (is_minus && contain_nonzero)
        {
            /* contain minus sign and nonzero digit */
            ft_is_negative(-1);
        }
        else
        {
            /* contain digit, positive or zero (including minus zero) */
            ft_is_negative(0);
        }
    }
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand where I was going wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <unistd.h>

void ft_is_negative(int n) { if (n >= 0) { write(1, "P", 1); } else { write(1, "N", 1); } }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**